# Android Application fastest parsing library or inbuilt method

Tags: android, web-services

I am working on android application where i will receive  a lot of data from webservice(XML format) and I want to have  library which can fetch bunch of records which i can display and next bunch of records.

I also work for iphone, i have a LIB2 parser for backend parsing.

Kindly help me with the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `SAXParser`http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html. I think this is the best solution to parse xml.